# Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) Android

Tags: android

I am a complete novice at Android and I am trying to add a splash screen following an online tutorial here: http://www.slideshare.net/YasmineSherif91/android-application-how-to-add-a-splash-screen-with-timer-tutorial-4

I am now getting the error Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) and I cannot for the life of me work out why. Any help much appreciated. Thanks
My code is below

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    Thread logoTimer - new Thread (){
        public void run(){
            try{
                    int logoTimer = 0;
                    while (logoTimer<5000){
                        sleep(100);
                        logoTimer-=logoTimer+100;
                        }
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.nrobson.mot2.Clearscreen"))
                    )
                    finally(
                            finish());
        }
    };
    }
    logoTimer.start();
```

Comment: Could you give more details on the error message. The exact text? Also, it looks like ``Thread logoTimer - new Thread ()`` should have an equals, not a minus. May be your problem.

Comment: you are not going to have any fun working on android if you don't take some time now and go back to brush up on your java syntax. You have extra brackets, and parenthesis in your code. I would also strongly suggest that you do not force your users to stare at your logo for 5 seconds before using your app. You are just wasting their time. If you have some data to load then do so in the background while your logo is showing otherwise just let them get to the app. No need to waste their time like this.

Comment: Thanks, that has sorted the thread problem out. The other error codes are Syntax error on token "finally", invalid 
 AssignmentOperator.

Comment: you are using a minus instead of equals, as thomas88wp stated. But seriously you need to get your java basics down before diving into android...

Answer (score 3):

You had tons of syntax errors. Try using:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while (logoTimer < 5000) {
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    logoTimer -= logoTimer + 100;
                }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.nrobson.mot2.Clearscreen"));
            } finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}
```

Here's a (possibly incomplete) list of errors you had:

- Trying to use `-` instead of `=`
- `logoTimer.start();` was outside your method body
- Using `(` and `)` for your `finally` block instead of `{` and `}`
- Missing `try-catch` block for `InterruptedException` when sleeping
- Missing semicolon at the end of `startActivity(new Intent("com.nrobson.mot2.Clearscreen"))`
- Misaligned brackets

Also, the line:

```
logoTimer -= logoTimer + 100;
```

Translates to:

```
logoTimer = logoTimer - (logoTimer + 100);
```

Are you sure you want that?